# How can I change Hibernate's SessionFactory's default schema setting at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate3

We configure our Session Factory bean in XML.  The default session name is read from a properties file that is in the resource folder of the code.  For a new purpose, I need to be able to change the default schema property to something else at runtime.  I cannot figure out how.

The session factory is created in the XML wiring as follows:

```
   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${oracle.default_schema}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            ... other properties ...
        </props>
    </property>
    ... lots of mapping files and annotated classes ...
```

I thought I could pull the session factory out of Spring's context, perhaps provide a Properties class to (I hoped) override the default session property and nothing else, and then continue on my way happily.

Unfortunately, when I try to get the session factory bean out of the context, it's of type `SessionFactoryImpl` and not `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.  This means the `setHibernateProperties()` method is not available to me.

I'm not sure if I can call `ALTER SESSION` either.  Because the session factory is obtained by our DAO classes in a library, I don't have an easy way of wrapping the session factory with the necessary code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple JPA config files, one for each environment you want to support, and then import it into your spring config.

```
<import resource="classpath:services-environment-${environment.name}.xml"/>
```

For me, there's a file for prod, test, and for each user, by setting the environment.name system property, the correct JPA configuration is loaded.